# how to remove unused js of a page with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

We have a website that uses jquery in its code, and because of this, jquery is not used much, which causes unused js to cause problems in Google search console, and Google page speed insight.
This is not a CMS website and is written by bootstrap and jQuery.
The problem of decreasing website performance is due to the presence of unused js in JQuery.
you can see this problem on https://i.stack.imgur.com/19ISI.png

I have another JavaScript file that is causing this problem, and for some reason I don't use CDN and I upload the files to my own host.
I also use another library and I have this problem with it as well.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: This question makes little sense, unfortunately. If you have a website that uses jQuery, why does that imply that it does not use it very much? Also, unused jQuery is not going to cause Google search issues, and I doubt it's much of a problem with page speed in realistic terms. You really have not posted enough details on the actual problems for anybody to help here.

Comment: Sounds like you're using a wordpress site;) Seriously, removing JS scripts via JS doesn't solve any problem. The only way to keep track of this issue (too much bloat) is to inspect an understand your actual code base/eco-system. Try to disable e.g unnecessary plugins or functions used by your templates.  Search for actual tutorials about script best practices and don't waste too much time on reading post written by self proclaimed "SEO-experts" (they s*ck and only want to sell you their plugin/service) ... if a search engine result starts with "10 best ..." skip and refine your query!

Comment: ... and please add more details to your description – ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or detailed info about your "eco-system" so CMS, page generator, HTML/CSS library/framework etc.